# Using the ternary operator: Is this legal syntax? The console doesn't tell me

Tags: javascript

So I have a bit of a problem, here is the basic version.

```
var x = 10;
(x < 5) ? call() : "" ;

function call() {
  alert('Less');
}
```

I want a way to give the question mark `if` statement "nothing" to do if it finds something to be false. Is what I am doing a legal move in JavaScript? Is there a better way to give the `if` "nothing" to do if it finds this false? The console does not catch any errors.

However when I tried:

```
var x = 10;
(x < 5) ? call() :;

function call() {
  alert('Less');
}
```

It gave me an Error as well as:

```
var x = 10;
(x < 5) ? call();

function call() {
  alert('Less');
}
```

Specifically what I am asking is: Is there a proper syntax to the question mark `if` to make it work without the `else` part? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use `if (x < 5) call();`

Comment: yeah @jfriend00, that's what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: You don't have to use the `if`, it's just the better way to do it.

Comment: I'll take your guy's advice, after all, I asked for it, so not taking it would be stupid. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: No @JakeGould It isnt. Read my question before accusing it of being a duplicate please. I was trying to see if there was no need for the else part of the ternary operator. And that other post uses JQuery, which is not what I want.

Comment: That didn't come up when I was typing it in... Thank you @OneKitten

Comment: The correct name is [*Conditional Operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12). It is *a* ternary opertaor, not *the* ternary operator. And you can do `x < 5? call() : null;` or any other expression that does nothing for the false case (such as `void 0` or `undefined` or whatever).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operators `||` and `&&`:

```
x < 5 && call();
```

But it's poor practice, just use an `if` without an `else`:

```
if (x < 5) {
  call();
}
```

Comment: So there isn't a way to do it the way I did? Oh well, But thanks for your help! I guess I will have to use the `if` without an `else`.

Comment: @Brendan You sound so disappointed by that fact.

Comment: Not like that, the ternary operator syntax is `exp ? exp : exp`, you need both branches.

Comment: That's what its actually called? Good to know, I will have to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

To do it your way, you have to put the conditional value into a dummy variable and make your function `call()` return something. This is a little bit messy:

```
var dummy = (x < 5) ? call() : "";
```

Like the other answers suggest, don't do this, even if you can. A bad semantic is like jumping off a plane without a parachute. It may be fine but more likely you will crash on something.

So, for what you are asking, the answer is "don't". The correct syntax for a condition is with the keyword `if`.

Comment: Putting the result in a dummy variable does not change whether or not it is legal syntax, nor is it better than the original code by the OP.

Comment: Edited, thanks for pointing out that there was an error. I didn't specify that the function should return something. Anyway, I'd never recommend this syntax. This is only to show that there is a way to do it.